# Most Efficient Python Based Crawler

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, web-crawler

I created a python crawler from scratch. it is very efficient,-I tried to crawl many websites (34) some of them are off, more than 400000 pages and it works like a charm. but sometimes it stuck in a loop by trying to crawl single page again and again. so please help me to figure out the possible solution (my guess:- it may be because of the characters like -"\n" so how can I filter these type of characters) and it's appreciable if you can test my script in different website and let me know, if you find any error.

the best thing about my python crawler is that you can also run it in parallel (i tested it by running 148 scripts in parallel works great and it saves time(as long as the website don't misunderstand crawling as a DDOS attack))

its highly appreciable if you also provide me the solution of error, you find.

I paste the code of my python script below. you can also download it from http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1397093

here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import MySQLdb as sql
import time
import warnings

print("starting")

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

db = sql.connect("localhost", "root", "arpit", "website")
cursor = db.cursor()
db.autocommit(True)

print("connected to database")

url = "http://www.example.com"
extension = ".com"
print("scrapping url -",url)

r = requests.head(url)
cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code)     
values(%s,'pending',%s)", [url, r.status_code])

cursor.execute("select status from urls where status ='pending' limit 1")
result = str(cursor.fetchone())

while (result != "None"):

cursor.execute("select urls from urls where status ='pending' limit 1")
result = str(cursor.fetchone())

s_url = result[2:-3]

cursor.execute("update urls set status = 'done' where urls= %s ", [s_url])

if "https" in url:
    url1 = url[12:]
else:
    url1 = url[11:]
zone = 0
while True:

    try:
        r = requests.get(s_url,timeout=60)
        break

    except:
        if s_url == "":

            print("done")
            break
        elif zone >= 4:
            print("this url is not valid -",s_url)
            break
        else:
            print("Oops!  may be connection was refused.  Try again...",s_url)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            zone = zone + 1

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all("a")

for x in links:
    a = x.get('href')
    if a is not None and a != "":

        if a != "" and a.find("\n") != -1:
            a = a[0:a.find("\n")]

        if a != "" and a[-1] == "/":
            a = a[0:-1]

        if a != "":
            common_extension = [',',' ',"#",'"','.mp3',"jpg",'.wav','.wma','.7z','.deb','.pkg','.rar','.rpm','.tar','.zip','.bin','.dmg','.iso','.toast','.vcd','.csv','.dat','.log','.mdb','.sav','.sql','.apk','.bat','.exe','.jar','.py','.wsf','.fon','.ttf','.bmp','.gif','.ico','.jpeg','.png','.part','.ppt','.pptx','.class','.cpp','.java','.swift','.ods','.xlr','.xls','.xlsx','.bak','.cab','.cfg','.cpl','.dll','.dmp','.icns','.ini','.lnk','.msi','.sys','.tmp','.3g2','.3gp','.avi','.flv','.h264','.m4v','.mkv','.mov','.mp4','.mpg','.vob','.wmv','.doc','.pdf','.txt']
            for ext in common_extension:
                if ext in a:
                    a = ""
                    break

        if a != "":
            if a[0:5] == '/http':
                a = a[1:]
            if a[0:6] == '//http':
                a = a[2:]

            if a[0:len(url1) + 12] == "https://www." + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [a, r.status_code])
            elif a[0:len(url1) + 11] == "http://www." + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [a, r.status_code])
            elif a[0:len(url1) + 8] == "https://" + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + (a[(a.find(extension + "/")) + 4:]), r.status_code])
            elif a[0:len(url1) + 7] == "http://" + url1:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + (a[(a.find(extension + "/")) + 4:]), r.status_code])
            elif a[0:2] == "//" and a[0:3] != "///" and "." not in a and "http" not in a and "www." not in a:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + a[1:], r.status_code])
            elif a[0:1] == "/" and a[0:2] != "//" and "." not in a and "http" not in a and "www." not in a:
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + a[0:], r.status_code])
            elif 'http' not in a and 'www.' not in a and "." not in a and a[0] != "/":
                cursor.execute("insert ignore into urls(urls,status,status_code) values(%s,'pending',%s)",
                               [url + '/' + a, r.status_code])

cursor.execute("alter table urls drop id")
cursor.execute("alter table urls add id int primary key not null  
auto_increment first")
print("new id is created")
```

Comment: Make sure that your scraping is in accordance with the policies of the websites that you scrape, or there could be serious legal implications.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to follow along with your code (think about renaming variables and trying to lump some of these 'if' statements together), but you can try creating a variable that stores the previous value, then compare the two URLs. Something like `for x in links: a = x.get('href') prev_a = a if a == prev_a ~do whatever`

Comment: my python crawler automatically saves all the fetched links to mysql server database for example: if the main domain has let say 50 sub-links, my crawler saves all the sub-link to MySQL server database and then fetch other links from previously saved sub-links and repeat the process again and again.                                                                          it;s highly appreciable if you try to run the script on your computer,- if possible.